# How to show the related tags in the node using when its load in drupal?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, nodes

I am using cctags module  for getting all the list of tags , I already stored the several tags for each node separately using the content type, now i need to display the specific tag when the node loads , but the cctags module will display all the tags in the term data.

```
     if(empty($nodevalue->field_beachestags)){
    $tagvale=array(explode(",",$nodevalue->field_beach_migratetagshidden[$nodevalue->language]['0']['value']));        
    foreach ($tagvale as $term_name) {
    foreach ($term_name as $termtag) {
        $terms_matched = taxonomy_get_term_by_name($termtag, 'tags'); // "beach_terms" is the machine name of vid 1.
        if ($terms_matched) {
            //We blindly use the first match. Not very elegant.
            $first_term = current($terms_matched);

            $nodevalue->field_beachestags[$nodevalue->language][]['tid'] = (array) $first_term->tid;
        } else {
            $term = new stdClass();
            $term->name = $termtag;
            $term->vid = 1; // Vid from the question.
            taxonomy_term_save($term);
            $nodevalue->field_beachestags[$nodevalue->language][]['tid'] = (array) $term->tid;
        }
    }
     }
 node_save($nodevalue);
 }
```

but there is a field called "field_data_field_tags " it does not contain any value for the reference of the node and the tags, I am not able to get the related tags to display for the node .

When i load the node i must display the related tags whichs is related to the field_beachestags. Any suggestion and help welcome .